# Помогите, пожалуйста, понять, что конкретно делает этот код

Tags: python

```
def iprimes_upto(limit):

    is_prime = [True] * limit
    for n in range(2, limit):
        if is_prime[n]:
            yield n
            for i in range(n*n, limit, n):
                is_prime[i] = False
primes = list(iprimes_upto(2000000))

print(sum(primes))
```

Данный код в конце выдает сумму простых чисел до двух миллионов. Я просто не понимаю что происходит построчно именно в самой функции и как генерируется список.

Comment: Всем спасибо большое! Теперь понял, как это работает!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы код правильно работал нужно исправить 6 строчку

```
def iprimes_upto(limit):  # Реализация алгоритма решето эратосфена
    is_prime = [True] * limit
    for n in range(2, limit):  # идем по всем числам из заданного промежутка
        if is_prime[n]:  # если число простое
            yield n  # возвращаем простое число но не заканчиваем функцию
            for i in range(n*2, limit, n):  # теперь все числа, которые могут получится умножением n на какоето число помечаем как непростые
                is_prime[i] = False


print(sum(iprimes_upto(10)))
```

Comment: Спасибо! А как именно происходит определение того, простое число или нет?

Comment: @8oDolaz загуглите решето эратосфена

Comment: @8oDolaz когда в списке находится простое число, оно возвращается как результат, а все числа позади него, если они на него делятся, помечаются как составные. Возвращается число 2 - отбрасываются все числа, делящиеся на 2. Возвращается 3 - отбрасываются делящиеся на 3. Потом 4, оно уже отброшено, идём дальше

Comment: Просто в строке *if is_prime[n]* вы подписали, что он определяет простое число или нет, но каких либо манипуляций в коде не происходит.

Comment: @8oDolaz В этой строке происходит проверка значения массива на true или false. Если вы этого не понимаете, очень советую внимательно прочитать статью про основы программирования.

Comment: извиняюсь, все понятно, спасибо огромное